# Extracting Data from an Array in JSON

Tags: php, json

Why does querying this JSON in this way not work?

**$weather_data**

```
{
   "coord":{
      "lon":-0.13,
      "lat":51.51
   },
   "sys":{
      "message":1.7255,
      "country":"GB",
      "sunrise":1430282118,
      "sunset":1430335221
   },
   "weather":[
      {
         "id":800,
         "main":"Clear",
         "description":"Sky is Clear",
         "icon":"01n"
      }
   ],
   "base":"stations",
   "main":{
      "temp":280.154,
      "temp_min":280.154,
      "temp_max":280.154,
      "pressure":1018.05,
      "sea_level":1026.07,
      "grnd_level":1018.05,
      "humidity":63
   },
   "wind":{
      "speed":3.3,
      "deg":253.501
   },
   "clouds":{
      "all":0
   },
   "dt":1430337359,
   "id":2643743,
   "name":"London",
   "cod":200
}
```

**query.php**

```
$json = json_decode($weather_data, TRUE);
$user_temp = $json['weather'][1]['main'];
```

My desired result is to get a value of "Clear" from inside that JSON.
Troublesome.

I'm new to this, I've done some searching around and I couldn't discover a solution, thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are zero based, you're trying to get the first item, and it would be `[0]`

```
$json = json_decode($weather_data, TRUE);
$user_temp = $json['weather'][0]['main'];
```

Comment: Oh damn, of course, I was that close, really? Thank you very much.